# How do I install and use the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit in my .NET 3.5 web applications?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, .net-3.5

How do I get it to work with my project?

http://ajax.asp.net/

http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit/

Comment: I have included it as written, but when dragging controls from the Toolbox, they still get a "green line" below the ajaxtoolkit tag - and the intellisense does not popup as expected... is there anything else needed?

Answer (score 38):

**Install the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit**

1. Download the ZIP file
   AjaxControlToolkit-Framework3.5SP1-DllOnly.zip
   from the [ASP.NET AJAX Control
   Toolkit Releases](http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16488) page of the
   CodePlex web site.
2. Copy the contents of this zip file
   directly into the bin directory of
   your web site.

**Update web.config**

3. Put this in your web.config under the <controls> section:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
       ...
       <system.web>
           ...
           <pages>
               ...
               <controls>
                   ...
                   <add tagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit"
                       namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
                       assembly="AjaxControlToolKit"/>
               </controls>
           </pages>
           ...
       </system.web>
       ...
   </configuration>
   ```

**Setup Visual Studio**

4. Right-click on the Toolbox and select "Add Tab", and add a tab called "AJAX Control Toolkit"
5. Inside that tab, right-click on the Toolbox and select "Choose Items..."
6. When the "Choose Toolbox Items" dialog appears, click the "Browse..." button. Navigate to your project's "bin" folder. Inside that folder, select "AjaxControlToolkit.dll" and click OK. Click OK again to close the Choose Items Dialog.

You can now use the controls in your web sites!

Comment: And don't forget to add <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %> at the top of your aspx page right after <%@ Page .... %>!

Answer (score 13):

You can easily install it by writing

`Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit` in package manager console.

for more information you can check this [link](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MasterPages and Content pages in your app - you also have the option of putting the ScriptManager on the Masterpage and then every ContentPage that uses that MasterPage will *NOT* need a script manager added. If you need some of the special configurations of the ScriptManager - like javascript file references - you can use a ScriptManagerProxy control on the content page that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

you will also need to have a asp:ScriptManager control on every page that you want to use ajax controls on.  you should be able to just drag the scriptmanager over from your toolbox one the toolkit is installed following Zack's instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It's really [simple](http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/archive/2010/04/16/installing-ajax-control-toolkit-4-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx), just download the latest toolkit from [Codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/90063) and add the extracted `AjaxControlToolkit.dll` to your toolbox in Visual Studio by right clicking the toolbox and selecting 'choose items'. You will then have the controls in your Visual STudio toolbox and using them is just a matter of dragging and dropping them onto your form, of course don't forget to add a `asp:ScriptManager` to every page that uses controls from the toolkit, or optionally include it in your master page only and your content pages will inherit the script manager.