# ajax web.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using AJAX Control Toolkit with Visual Studio 2005. I don't have the vs template so I don't know what goes in my web.config?

Thanks,
rod.

Comment: Can you specify what features you're trying to enable, or what problem you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your answer (and many others concerning the AJAX Control Toolkit) on the [ASP.Net Control Toolkit FAQ page](http://forums.asp.net/t/1422287.aspx). See Question 3.3 for web.config settings.

You can also read the [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-asp-net-ajax-control-toolkit-in-my-net-3-5-web-appl/40118#40118).