# Unknown server tag <ajax:Grid>

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am learning ASP.net Ajax. I want to pull data from a db table and populate it on a grid as shown in the following tutorial.

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/aspnetajaxgridandpager.aspx

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="TheScriptManager" runat="server">
  <Services>
    <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/DataService.asmx" />
  </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<ajax:Grid ID="grid1" runat="server"></ajax:Grid>
```

I have added reference to "ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll"

But I am getting the error "Unknown server tag 'ajax:Grid' ".   After some search I found this solution from the following website.

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/271778-DataGrid-AJAX.aspx

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1 or asp" %>
```

But this solution is not working for me.

How can I resolve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the TagPrefix attribute to "ajax" instead of "cc1 or asp".

Comment: @Sandeep You most likely don't have the AjaxControlToolkit library referenced correctly in your site if you are still receiving the error.  Make sure your web application has a reference to the library.  Here is some more information on installing the Ajax Control Toolkit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-asp-net-ajax-control-toolkit-in-my-net-3-5-web-appl.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered some problem with this project. So, inside Northwind solution we have two projects: web site Northwind and library Ajax.Control.  What you have mentioned in your question was a control from this library. But, unfortunately, in my case, I have revealed that library was build using Framework 2.0 version but contain a reference to namespace System.Web.Extensions which belong  as minimum to Framework 3.5. So, I have change target framework for Ajax.Control project to Framework 3.5 and all is working now.