# Unable to create type 'ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager'. Could not load file or assembly

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We are in the process of migrating from a Windows Server 2003 to a Windows Server 2012.  Everything was built prior to my starting in this position, added to that, I am just not sure what needs done so here is my question.

I moved the code to the new server but when I try and access the webpage, I am getting the following error:

Unable to create type 'ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager'. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

There is a copy of the AjaxControlToolkit.dll in the /bin folder of the application, but is this error telling me I need to install the AjaxControlToolkit on the new server as well and if so, can I install the latest version, or do I need a specific version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-asp-net-ajax-control-toolkit-in-my-net-3-5-web-app

Comment: I have all that is listed in my project and web.config

Comment: <pages validateRequest="false">
   <controls>
 <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" />
   </controls>
  </pages>

Comment: Did you upgrade your project to the latest v15.1 Ajax Control Toolkit?

Comment: No, I was using the same version of the toolkit in the new environment.  Would an update / upgrade be needed?